# Local kernel crashes when I apply NDSolveValue to my problem

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I'm trying to solve a simple Laplace's equation, but using `NDSolve` or `NDSolveValue` the Wolfram System beeps; the message is

> The kernel Local has quit (exited) during the course of an evaluation.

I hope someone will help me to solve this problem.

Here is the code of a simplified version of my problem.

```
Ω = 
  ImplicitRegion[
    0 <= x <= 34 && -18 <= y <= 0 && 
      ! (12 < x < 15 && -12 < y || 15 < x < 20 && -3 < y || 
         20 < x < 23 && -7 < y || 23 < x < 34 && -3 < y), 
    {x, y}];

RegionPlot[Ω, AspectRatio -> 0.5]

NDSolveValue[
  {Laplacian[φ[x, y], {x, y}] == 
     NeumannValue[0, 
       x == 0 && -18 < y < 0 || 0 < x < 34 && y == -18 || 
       x == 34 && -18 < y < -3 || x == 23 && -7 < y < -3 || 
       20 < x < 23 && y == -7 || x == 20 && -7 < y < -3 || 
       15 < x < 20 && y == -3 || x == 15 && -12 < y < -3 || 
       12 < x < 15 && y == -12 || x == 12 && -12 < y < 0], 
   DirichletCondition[φ[x, y] == 1.5, 0 <= x <= 12 && y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[φ[x, y] == 0.4, 23 <= x <= 34 && y == -3]}, 
  φ, {x, y} ∈ Ω]

ContourPlot[%[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: It works with `\[CapitalOmega] = 
 Polygon[{{0, -18}, {34, -18}, {34, -3}, {23, -3}, {23, -7}, {20, -7}, {20, -3}, {15, -3}, {15, -12}, {12, -12}, {12, 0}, {0, 0}}]`.  
I don't know why your syntax doesn't work.

Comment: Your sample code runs fine on my system:  Mathematica 10.1.0 on MacOS 10.12.2, MacBook Pro  11,3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The region, as you specified it, has a troublesome corner.

```
\[CapitalOmega] = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= x <= 34 && -18 <= y <= 
     0 && ! (12 < x < 15 && -12 < y || 15 < x < 20 && -3 < y || 
       20 < x < 23 && -7 < y || 23 < x < 34 && -3 < y), {x, y}];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ToBoundaryMesh[\[CapitalOmega]]["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The mesh generation has trouble with that thin line. Changing the region a bit is better.

```
\[CapitalOmega] = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= x < 34 && -18 <= y <= 
     0 && ! (12 < x < 15 && -12 < y || 15 < x < 20 && -3 < y || 
       20 < x < 23 && -7 < y || 23 < x < 34 && -3 < y), {x, y}];
ToBoundaryMesh[\[CapitalOmega]]["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A better resolution can be had with this some options. (Though specifying the region as a polygon is probably best in this case, as the region is not curved)

```
ToBoundaryMesh[\[CapitalOmega], 
  "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"RegionPlot", 
    "SamplePoints" -> 41}]["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This them works:

```
ifun = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[\[CurlyPhi][x, y], {x, y}] == 
    NeumannValue[0, 
     x == 0 && -18 < y < 0 || 0 < x < 34 && y == -18 || 
      x == 34 && -18 < y < -3 || x == 23 && -7 < y < -3 || 
      20 < x < 23 && y == -7 || x == 20 && -7 < y < -3 || 
      15 < x < 20 && y == -3 || x == 15 && -12 < y < -3 || 
      12 < x < 15 && y == -12 || x == 12 && -12 < y < 0], 
   DirichletCondition[\[CurlyPhi][x, y] == 1.5, 
    0 <= x <= 12 && y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[\[CurlyPhi][x, y] == 0.4, 
    23 <= x <= 34 && y == -3]}, \[CurlyPhi], {x, 
    y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"RegionPlot", 
          "SamplePoints" -> 41}}}}]

ContourPlot[ifun[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
  PlotRange -> All] // Quiet
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]